# Ansible Return Value - Need IP Adress

Tags: automation, ansible, return-value

We are currently using Ansible in conjunction with OpenStack. I've written a playbook (to deploy new server via OpenStack) where i use the module `os_server` where i use `auto_ip: yes`, the new server will become an IP Address assigned from the OpenStack Server.

If I use the `-vvvv` output command, i get a **long output** where in the middle of that output an IP-Address is listed.

So, cause I am a lazy guy, I want to put just this IP Address in a variable and let me show this IP Address in an extra field.
It should look like this:

```
"........output stuf.....
................................
.............................
..............................
..............................."

"The IP Adress of the New server is ....."
```

Is there any possibility you know to put these IP Address Field in a variable or to filter that output to the IP Address?

If you need an screenshot to see what I mean, no problem just write it and I'll give it to you!

Comment: Please edit the title of your question. "Address" with two d. Put a reference to Openstack and os_server in the title. Like this I will not upvote your question, even if it is a very good one.

Answer (score 3):

Ansible OpenStack module uses `shade` python package to create a server.

According to the `shade` source code, [`create_server`](https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-infra/shade/tree/shade/openstackcloud.py#n4080) method returns a dict representing the created server.

Try to register the result of `os_server` and debug it. The IP Address should be there.

Example :

```
- name: launch a compute instance
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: launch an instance
    os_server:
      state: present
      ...
      auto_ip: yes
    register: result

- debug: var=result
```

Also, you can have a look to this [sample playbook](https://github.com/tourunen/pouta-spark-course/blob/master/playbooks/cluster.yml#L161) which does exactly this.

Here's an excerpt:

```
- name: create cluster notebook VM
  register: notebook_vm
  os_server:
    name: "{{ cluster_name }}-notebook"
    flavor: "{{ notebook_flavor }}"
    image: "CentOS-7.0"
    key_name: "{{ ssh_key }}"
    network: "{{ network_name }}"
    security_groups:
      - "{{ cluster_name }}-notebook"
    auto_ip: yes
    boot_from_volume: "{{ notebook_boot_from_volume }}"
    terminate_volume: yes
    volume_size: 25

- name: add notebook to inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ cluster_name }}-notebook"
    groups: notebooks
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{ notebook_vm.openstack.private_v4 }}"
    ansible_ssh_user: cloud-user
    public_ip: "{{ notebook_vm.openstack.public_v4 }}"
    public_name: "{{ lookup('dig', notebook_vm.openstack.public_v4 + '/PTR', wantlist=True)[0] }}"
  tags: ['vm_creation']
```

Comment: I think the exact name of the value is:

    "{{ notebook_vm.openstack.accessIPv4 }}"